# How to cover the border on active tab when the border is not on ul element

Tags: html, css

I know how to remove(cover) the border on active tab when the border is set on ul element like [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs), by setting `margin-right: -1px` on the tab element.

However, how can I do this when the border is on another panel? I set the `margin-right: -1px`, but it doesn't make sense......

[Here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6fnL13w4/), I want to break the border between the active tab and the right side panel.

Comment: You're running into z-index issues. First you must make sure that your tabs are drawn above your content pane. https://jsfiddle.net/gwpff95z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set `position: relative` and a `z-index` to put the li above the panel

```
li {
  color: #999;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /* add these two rules */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Yeah! `z-index, top, left` ... not work on `static` position (browser default)

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple solutions. One is to first make sure that the tabs are above the content panel and their right borders coincide. Then you can color the right border same as background color of the panel, i.e. white. As shown here https://jsfiddle.net/6fnL13w4/1/

```
.left {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  float: left;

  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}
li.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to set position property. Just add  `position:relative` it should work fine.

Comment: You are right. It seems `z-index` doesn't work without setting `position` property.